# Get Clojure map from POST request

Tags: clojure

Here is my code:

```
(ns cowl.server
  (:use compojure.core)
  (:require [ring.adapter.jetty :as jetty]
            [ring.middleware.params :as params]
            [ring.middleware.json :refer [wrap-json-response]]
            [ring.util.response :refer [response]]
            [clojure.data.json :as json]
            [cowl.db :as db]))

(defroutes main-routes
  (POST "/api/news/as-read" { body :body }
    (str (json/read-str (slurp body))))))

(def app
  (-> main-routes
      wrap-json-response))

(defn serve []
  (jetty/run-jetty app {:port 3000}))
```

If I post this JSON: `{ "name": "demas" }` I get `{"name" "demas"}`.  But this is not a Clojure map.

I need something like `(:name (json/read-str (slurp body)))`.  How can I get it ?

Comment: `{"name" "demas"}` is indeed a clojure map. you can have anything for a key and for a value. and there are no colons in a clojure map.

Comment: Thanks. It helps me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of handling body JSON parsing by yourself, you can use [`ring.middleware.json/wrap-json-body`](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring-json#wrap-json-body). Just modify your middleware setup:

```
(def app
  (-> main-routes
      wrap-json-response
      (wrap-json-body {:keywords? true})))
```

and your request `:body` will become JSON parsed to Clojure data.

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to use the `keywordize-keys` function:

http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.walk/keywordize-keys

```
(ns xyz.core
  (:require [clojure.walk :as walk]))

(walk/keywordize-keys {"a" 1 "b" 2})
;;=> {:a 1 :b 2}
```

You will probably also find that the Cheshire lib is the best way to process JSON in Clojure:  https://github.com/dakrone/cheshire#decoding

```
;; parse some json
(parse-string "{\"foo\":\"bar\"}")
;; => {"foo" "bar"}

;; parse some json and get keywords back
(parse-string "{\"foo\":\"bar\"}" true)  ; true -> want keyword keys
;; => {:foo "bar"}

;; parse some json and munge keywords with a custom function
(parse-string "{\"foo\":\"bar\"}" (fn [k] (keyword (.toUpperCase k))))
;; => {:FOO "bar"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use :key-fn function as well:

```
(json/read-str (return :body)
               :key-fn keyword)
```

Doing this you will parse your JSON to default map syntax.